# Why iPhone safari breaks shadows on elements in PDF?

Tags: pdf, mobile-safari

I have this css rule. And I generate PDF from html via puppeteer or jsreports.

```
div {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1rem #f1f2f9;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1rem #f1f2f9;
}
```

And for some elements box-shadow not seen correct.

[image: iphone pdf shadow problem]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

When you add **filter** opacity 1, it fixes that problem.

```
div {  
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1rem #f1f2f9;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1rem #f1f2f9;
  -webkit-filter: opacity(1);
}
```

if it hides your inner elements, add filter opacity 1 to them too.

Comment: Saved me thanks works with text-shadow too